# Scrape anchor (<a>) html tags

Tags: html, regex

I need to scrape `<a>` tags in HTML.

My goal is to scrape tags that have valid links inside their href attribute.

I think I'm very close to the answer, and this is the regex I wrote:

```
<a .*href=("|').*\.asp("|').*?>.*?<\/a>
```

http://regexr.com/3d989

**FIRST ISSUE:**

Result:

```
<a id='topnavbtn_tutorials' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("tutorials")' title='Tutorials'>TUTORIALS <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a id='topnavbtn_references' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("references")' title='References'>REFERENCES <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a id='topnavbtn_examples' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("examples")' title='Examples'>EXAMPLES <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a href='/forum/default.asp'>FORUM</a>
```

and I only need:

```
<a href='/forum/default.asp'>FORUM</a>
```

**SECOND ISSUE:**

Result:

```
<a href='/html/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='HTML Tutorial'>HTML</a><a href='/css/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='CSS Tutorial'>CSS</a><a href='/js/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='JavaScript Tutorial'>JAVASCRIPT</a><a href='/sql/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='SQL Tutorial'>SQL</a><a href='/php/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='PHP Tutorial'>PHP</a><a href='/bootstrap/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='Bootstrap Tutorial'>BOOTSTRAP</a><a href='/jquery/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='jQuery Tutorial'>JQUERY</a><a href='/angular/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='Angular Tutorial'>ANGULAR</a><a href='/xml/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='XML Tutorial'>XML</a>
```

and I need them as separate results:

```
<a href='/html/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='HTML Tutorial'>HTML</a>

<a href='/css/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='CSS Tutorial'>CSS</a>

<a href='/js/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='JavaScript Tutorial'>JAVASCRIPT</a>
```

and so on...

Comment: "this is the regex I wrote" — That's a link. Put your code in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$string = "<a href='/html/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='HTML Tutorial'>HTML</a><a href='/css/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='CSS Tutorial'>CSS</a><a href='/js/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='JavaScript Tutorial'>JAVASCRIPT</a><a href='/sql/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='SQL Tutorial'>SQL</a><a href='/php/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='PHP Tutorial'>PHP</a><a href='/bootstrap/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='Bootstrap Tutorial'>BOOTSTRAP</a><a href='/jquery/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='jQuery Tutorial'>JQUERY</a><a href='/angular/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='Angular Tutorial'>ANGULAR</a><a href='/xml/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='XML Tutorial'>XML</a>";

preg_match_all('%<a href=\'/.*?\'>.*?</a>%s', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    echo $matches[0][$i];
}
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
<a href='/html/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='HTML Tutorial'>HTML</a>
<a href='/css/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='CSS Tutorial'>CSS</a>
<a href='/js/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='JavaScript Tutorial'>JAVASCRIPT</a>
<a href='/sql/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='SQL Tutorial'>SQL</a>
<a href='/php/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='PHP Tutorial'>PHP</a>
<a href='/bootstrap/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='Bootstrap Tutorial'>BOOTSTRAP</a>
<a href='/jquery/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='jQuery Tutorial'>JQUERY</a>
<a href='/angular/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='Angular Tutorial'>ANGULAR</a>
<a href='/xml/default.asp' class='w3-hide-small' title='XML Tutorial'>XML</a>
```

---

DEMO:

https://ideone.com/eFHU8n

---

**NOTE:**

[Why you shouldn't use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/797495)

Comment: 1. Can you apply your regex in this link http://regexr.com/   ?

2. What is the alternative of using regex if I need certain tags from a long XHTML string ?

Comment: 1. Yes, you just need to escape the forward slashes `<a href=\'\/.*?\'>.*?<\/a>` 2. Use PHP DomDocument - here's a tutorial http://www.binarytides.com/php-get-links-on-a-page-with-domdocument/

Comment: Lobido now I can't get these kind of results: '<a target="_top" href="colors_ncol.asp">Color NCol</a>' 

(where href is not the first attribute)

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't capture all possible cases of href with .asp links

Answer (score 1):

**Updated. See below.**

If you have the HTML in string form, you can do something like this:

```
// split the string up by anchor tags
// nested anchor tags is illegal, so this seems feasible:
var anchorArray = str.replace(/><a/g, '>¶<a').split('¶'); // ¶ is a placeholder to split

var matches = [];
var re = /<a .*href=["'].*\.asp["'].*?>.*?<\/a>/g;

// filter out the anchor elements with actual links in the final HTML
anchorArray.filter(function(element) { 
    if (re.test(element)) {
        matches.push(element); // keep the match in an array (2nd condition)
        return false; 
    }
    else return true;       
});

var returnedHTML = anchorArray.join('');  // HTML w/o actual links (1st condition)
```

Note that the preferred means of parsing HTML is not with regex, but with an HTML parser.

Comment: This solution gives a false positive outcome: `<a id='topnavbtn_tutorials' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("tutorials")' title='Tutorials'>TUTORIALS <i class='fa fa-caret-down'>`

Comment: Try this: https://regex101.com/r/mN8zN2/3 (directly from the example in the link by OP)

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I'll put my solution on hold by deletion for now.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
var matches = [];

input_content.replace(/[^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">/w*<\a>)/g, function () {
    matches.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
});
```

It returns all matches to the matches variable as array!

Comment: This only provides 4 matches. There are more links that qualify